# Can you set Black so that it doesn't put ... statements on a newline?

Tags: python, python-black

I mostly agree with many of Black's formatting choices, including putting `pass` on a new line since usually it means I will implement the function later, but when I truly *do* want a function to be empty, I use `...`, but then Black still puts it on a new line. Is there a Black setting to disable this? (Note: I still want it to put `pass` statements on a newline, if possible.

Comment: Black is (for better or worse, and with a small number of exceptions) unconfigurable *intentionally*. You either buy into its changes, or you don't use it. "Black is the uncompromising Python code formatter. **By using it, you agree to cede control** over minutiae of hand-formatting. In return, Black gives you speed, determinism, and freedom from pycodestyle nagging about formatting. You will save time and mental energy for more important matters."

Comment: Wildly tangential, I would consider using `pass` for intentionally empty functions, and a doc string to document a function whose implementation has been deferred for the time being. A doc string alone is syntactically sufficient to complete a `def` statement.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I kind of like that even though I'm using decorators; it looks pretty good. The only problem is with classes... I also need this to work with classes, I know it's niche, but the only other way I can think of it working is trying to make documentation with it, which wouldn't make sense for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer because there is no indication that this doesn't work with classes based on my testing.

You could declare your "empty" functions as lambdas: `empty = lambda: ...` - black won't reformat the lambda into a secondary line.

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.val = 1
...   func = lambda self: self.val
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.func()
1
```

Comment: Even though PEP-8 itself is not set in stone, violating it to appease a 3rd-party code formatter seems backwards.